# Correctly implementing Recursive methods in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

repeat_purchases_percent is a method in my Category model.  All parentless categories are guarenteed to have a value for future_purchases_percent in the database.  Subcategories may or may not have a future_purchases_percent.  if they do, i want to use that value.  If not, I want to use the parent's value and so on.

I tried a recursive method.

```
def future_purchases_percent
  if self.future_purchases_percent.nil?
    Category.find(self.parent_id).future_purchases_percent
  else
    future_purchases_percent
  end
end
```

This gets stuck in a loop where it keeps evaluating:

```
if self.future_purchases_percent.nil?
```

how can i correctly implement this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your method gets stuck because it has the same name than the attribute (so it's calling itself), pick a different name.
2. Notice that this conditional is nothing more than a simple `a || b` expression.
3. You should add a `belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :class_name => :Category` to this model.

Now, with everything in place, you can write real declarative code:

```
def safe_future_purchases_percent
  future_purchases_percent || parent.safe_future_purchases_percent
end
```

Comment: Think you got an extra `end` in there. Looks bueno otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, that indentation level seemed to be asking for an `end` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def repeat_purchases_percent
    if self.future_purchases_percent.nil?
      Category.find(self.parent_id).repeat_purchases_percent
    else
      future_purchases_percent
    end
  end
```

Basically your problem is that you named your method the same thing as the field and then immediately call it. You should instead name the method like you said `repeat_purchases_percent` and only recurse into it when the `future_purchases_percent` is nil.